# How do I build a software update software which Could update itself?

Tags: c#, c++, software-update

How do I handle this case which upate the  update software itself?It must termanate the process of update software,then everything has been stop?any hints or tips for this issues?I'm using visual c# and c++,and I dont like use Microsoft one click,because It's great limited you have to use WIndows

Comment: Hey,Why give me a negative score?Im really don't know How do I do this, and before I post this thread ,I have searched Google,I can't find the answer,so I asked how to build a software to update software,What I have done wrong?you shouldn't give me a negative score,It's unfair

Answer (score 0):

Run a separate installer application which does the installation. Preferably, your "update software" should only be responsible for recognizing when update is required and then triggering the update installation, not performing the actual installation. In which case, updating the "update software" itself is not an issue, since the installer can just stop the "update software", update it, and then restart it. If you are planning on doing this yourself, just make sure that you are extremely rigorous in your method to protect against corruption and faulty state of the software. Writing this kind of software requires great care in covering all possible edge cases where things can go terrible wrong resulting in huge problems if this "update software" is deployed on many machines.